# How to list NEURON section properties/information?

Tags: python, neural-network, biological-neural-network, neuron-simulator

In NEURON simulator, is there a way to list properties of a section other than iterating over each property individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the **NEURON GUI**, you could also find section properties in the NEURON's control menu:

**Tools-> Model View**

This will open a ModelView window which has section and segment details such as:

- **Type of cells**: real cells/ artificial cells
- **NetCon** objects
- **LinearMechanisms** objects
- **Density Mechanisms**
- **Point Processes**

If you click on each property, a drop-down menu appears showing the details of the property selected

You could also **view the structure of the model** if you click on the cell type (real/artificial cells).

Answer (score 1):

There is the [`psection()`](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/static/py_doc/modelspec/programmatic/topology.html#psection) method. Once the section of interest is `push()`ed. Typing `psection()` or, from Python, `h.psection(sec=your_section)` will produce the following example result:

```
>>> h.psection(sec=h.Granule[0].soma)

Granule[0].soma { nseg=1  L=8  Ra=80
    /*location 0 attached to cell 5*/
    /* First segment only */
    insert morphology { diam=8}
    insert capacitance { cm=4}
    insert pas { g_pas=0 e_pas=-65}
    insert kamt { gbar_kamt=0}
    insert nax { sh_nax=15 gbar_nax=0}
    insert na_ion { ena=60}
    insert kdrmt { gbar_kdrmt=0}
    insert k_ion { ek=-90}
    insert Exp2Syn { tau1=5 tau2=50 e=0}
    insert IClamp { del=50 dur=200 amp=0.09}
}
```

Comment: Pushing a section is generally bad form because so many things can be affected by the section stack. It's better to use the sec= keyword argument which constrains the effects, e.g. h.psection(sec=h.Granule[0].soma); in NEURON 7.6+, there's also a psection method that returns a data structure that your code can analyze.

Comment: Thx for the tip @ramcdougal